# Servlet Filter: How to get all the headers from servletRequest?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

Here is how my `WebFilter` looks like

```
@WebFilter("/rest/*")
public class AuthTokenValidatorFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final Enumeration<String> attributeNames = servletRequest.getAttributeNames();
        while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("{attribute} " + servletRequest.getParameter(attributeNames.nextElement()));
        }

        final Enumeration<String> parameterNames = servletRequest.getParameterNames();
        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("{parameter} " + servletRequest.getParameter(parameterNames.nextElement()));
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I tried to find out online as to how to get values for `HTTP headers` coming from request.

I did not find anything, so I tried to enumerate on `servletRequest.getAttributeNames()` and `servletRequest.getParameterNames()` without knowing anything, but I do not get any headers.

**Question**
How can I get all the headers coming from the request?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Typecast `ServletRequest` into `HttpServletRequest` (only if `ServletRequest request` is an `instanceof` `HttpServletRequest`).

Then you can use `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()` and `HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames()` method.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();

    if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                    System.out.println("Header: " + httpRequest.getHeader(headerNames.nextElement()));
            }
    }

    //doFilter
    chain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
}
```

Comment: @BuhakeSindi are there indicators under what circumstances `ServletRequest` might be sth. different than an `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: 'HttpServletReqiest' IS A 'ServletRequest'. It is a sub-interface of. ServletRequest. There can be various classes/interfaces of ServletRequest such as 'PortletRequest' hence its always to do an 'instanceof' check for various servlet types.

Comment: Why getHeaderNames(); missed some header like x-forward-for, keep-alive detail etc?

Comment: @UnKnown those headers are populated by the proxy servers. It has to be configured on server level. The Servlet just returns the parameters set by those servers.

Answer (score 84):

With Java 8+ you can use a stream to collect request headers:

```java
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

Map<String, String> headers = Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaderNames())
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(h -> h, httpRequest::getHeader));
```

**UPDATED**

@Matthias reminded me that headers can have multiple values:

**`Map<String, List<String>>`**

```java
Map<String, List<String>> headersMap = Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaderNames())    
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(), 
        h -> Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaders(h))
    ));
```

**`org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders`**

```java
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaderNames())
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        h -> Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaders(h)),
        (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
        HttpHeaders::new
    ));
```

https://gist.github.com/Cepr0/fd5d9459f17da13b29126cf313328fe3

Comment: did you try to compile this?

Comment: I had to tweak it slightly for Spring - ```response.getHeaderNames()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        h -> new ArrayList<>(response.getHeaders(h)),
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
                        HttpHeaders::new
                ));```

Comment: @bobmarksie in your variant you are using `response`, but the question was about  `request`. Unfortunately `HttpServletRequest#getHeaderNames` returns `Enumeration`, not `Collection`.

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0! Still found your answer very useful, even though I was using it in a different way.

Comment: Especially gist url is useful to test and gets clarified all doubts.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider that the same HTTP header can occur multiple times with different values:

```
Map<String, Serializable> headers = Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(h -> h, h -> {
    ArrayList<String> headerValues = Collections.list(request.getHeaders(h));
    return headerValues.size() == 1 ? headerValues.get(0) : headerValues;
}));
```

Comment: Please don't mix `String` and `ArrayList` in `Serializable`. When consuming the `Map`, I would need to `instanceof` the values again.

Answer (score 1):

In a spring boot application, this works inside any method (with Java 8)

```
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import java.util.Collections;
    
...
...

    public void anyMethod(){
        HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        Collections.list(req.getHeaderNames()).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```